# Create SPAN around the selected text in a DIV dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in my HTML page as follows:

```
    <div class="well editor" id="highlighted-text" 
style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;height:500px;" contenteditable></div>
```

When I select a portion of a text inside the div and click on a button, I want to highlight the selected text.

I understand that this can be done by adding a span with a class selector, around the selected text, but I am having trouble creating the span around the selected text:

```
var node = window.getSelection().focusNode;
$(node).wrapInner("<b></b>");
```

This doesn't work. Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I got it... I did this:

```
var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
var span= document.createElement("span");
span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
span.appendChild(selectedText);
selection.insertNode(span);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you do not need to create such a SPAN by using the selection pseduo CSS attribute for styling:
https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Comment: I want the selection background to remain after the highlight button click.